# How to select Regolith Linux for less RAM usage

Tags: ram

My computer has 8 GB of RAM. I am using Xubuntu 21.10, it is fast but it has no auto tiling. In my daily work, I mostly use LibreOffice Calc for calculation with complicated sheets and open many windows for watching various documents, so it needs more RAM. From option 2, https://regolith-linux.org/docs/getting-started/install/#ppa-install , will RAM be used more than Option 1, https://regolith-linux.org/docs/getting-started/install/#option-1-regolith-linux-via-installer ? And do I have to move from Xubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 for Option 2 ?

Comment: I cannot answer this entire question, but I can tell you that you cannot/should not move to Ubuntu 21.04 as that release is no longer supported. Current supported releases are 18.04, 20.04, and 21.10. By the end of the month we'll also have 22.04.

Comment: Also note for Xubuntu (a *flavor* of Ubuntu) the 18.04 release is already EOL - https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ as *flavors* have 3 years of supported life, where as 5 years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud...  thus I'd avoid 18.04 too unless switching to the *heavier* GNOME desktop.

Comment: 8 GB of RAM should be quite good even for opening quite a lot of complicated sheets. It would be different if you were referring to say 2 GB. Even if you really manage to fill all that RAM, swap memory will work rather well in this case and keep it workable. Better also evaluate your workflow and see whether you need all of this in RAM at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not make a meaningful difference in memory usage if you install Regolith in Ubuntu then switch to a Regolith session compared to when you would install the Regolith distribution.

Installing Regolith on a 21.10, then upgrading also will not make a meaningful difference over upgrading to 22.04 then installing Regolith.

In all scenario's, you are using essentially similar software on a similar base. Even if one way leads to a few more system services running than another way, you will not, for practical purposes, notice any difference.